# Perl: Strip out part of a string in an array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, substring, substr

I read all the questions that looked similar and am not gleaning an answer.

I saw a lot of "remove this or add that" but not a "move to another array..."

This question is below all of you but I am a Perl Newblet and could really use an elegant solution help.

I have an array with an unknown # of elements, each element containing a string similar to `{img_names_will_change.jpg}some unknown text`.

I need a subroutine that will strip the `{yadayada.jpg}` from each element and add the `yadayada.jpg` portion to a second array.

However, I still need each element in the original array to survive but without the `{....}`.

I looked into using substr or regex but got lost in the syntax.

I'll be RTFM on regex as well.

Comment: The solution below works well for all but doesn't remove the "{img.jpg}" substring from each element of the original array.  Anyway to make that happen as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  Just added the rest of the string into `$2` and applied it to `$original`.  Thanks Paulchenkiller!

```
foreach my $orignal ( @original ) {

#Extracts the text from within "{}" and pushes it into @images       
if ( $original =~ m/{(\w+\.\w+)}(.*)/ ) {

push @images, $1;

#Strips "{..}" out of @original
$original = $2;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, this could be a solution:

```
my @names = (
  '{img_names_will_change.jpg}some unknown text',
  '{img_names_will_change.jpg}some unknown text',
  '{img_names_will_change.jpg}some unknown text'
);
my @extract;
foreach my $name ( @names ) {
  if ( $name =~ m/{(\w+\.\w+)}/ ) {
    push @extract, $1;
  }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @extract;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = 'img_names_will_change.jpg';
$VAR2 = 'img_names_will_change.jpg';
$VAR3 = 'img_names_will_change.jpg';
```

Extracting the Imagename with `{(\w+\.\w+)}` and push it into another array.

Comment: that looks like it may work but why didn't you just do "foreach (@names){ if ($name =~ ....."  Why create a $name variable? Also, does this strip the "{...}" from the @names array elements?  Awesome work btw. Can we give points to people for thanks???

Comment: I meant "if ($_ =~ ..."

Comment: There is a arrow on the left side for upvotes/downvotes and a "accept this answer" if you are the OP.
Back to your answer: Its recommend to give variables inside loops Names. this is for example if you have two loops. You cant say for sure, which `$_` is used. Its also more readable.

Comment: Works perfectly to copy the img.jpg stuff but doesn't remove the {img.jpg} from the original elements.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to remove it, use substitution `s///`. so its something like `if ( $name =~ s/{(\w+\.\w+)}//r ) {`